# Problem understanding the output of Around

Tags: around

I'm working with Mathematica 12. I have a simple example

```
H0= Around[a,b]
```

I calculate $H0^2$, and the output is  $H0^2 = a^2 \pm 2 Abs[a b]$

Next I calculate $H0*H0$, and the output is  $H0*H0= a^2 \pm (2)^{1/2} * (a^2 b^2 )^ {1/2}$.
They differ by $(2)^{1/2}$, this is right? They should be equal?

Comment: With `H0 H0` the two `Around` objects are considered independent, leading to the difference you observe.

Comment: Then if I want to calculate $H0^2$ the correct  output is  the first one?

Comment: Note that the documentation for `Around` uses the term *approximate* a lot.  If you really *know* that $H0$ has a normal distribution with mean $a$ and standard deviation $b$, then $H0^2$ will have a mean of $a^2+b^2$ and a standard deviation of $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2a^2 b^2+b^4}$.

Comment: Just as `(a + t*b)^2 , -1 <= t <= 1;` is different from
`(a + t*b) (a + s*b), -1 <= t <= 1 && -1 <= s <= 1;`